# Regex error on special characters

Tags: c#

Code:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"A(\S");

foreach (Match match in rx.Matches(strinG))
{
  int ii = match.Index;
  Console.WriteLine(ii);
 }
```

gives error during run-time,

```
system argument exception - " A(\S" not enough )' ".
```

Can anybody help me, how to solve this ?

Answer (score 4):

i assume you're searching for a parenthesis, then backslash it.

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"A\(\S");
```